# AS3 - Strange Error 1010 Occurrence

Tags: actionscript-3, typeerror

I'm receiving the error:

```
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
```

The term it's referring to is a movieclip that is created. The creation code is as follows:

```
var Cursor = new CursorImg();
GameMenu.addChild(Cursor);
```

And here is where it is accessed:

```
GameMenu.Cursor.gotoAndStop(1);
```

I have no idea what's wrong with this, but when this is triggered, I get that error. I've compared it with other code that works, and it is exactly the same except for the naming of the movieclip, and its parent.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Thank you for all of your answers, the problem is now fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your code snippet, the `Cursor` variable is function local, as it's defined inside some function instead of being defined outside any functions, this way it'll be a property of a class. So, separate `var cursor:MovieClip;` from `cursor=new CursorImg();` and put the former outside of any functions, and test again. I guess you need to refer to that 'cursor' pretty often, this way `getChildByName` call will drop performance somehow.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what's going on with the limited amount of info posted but it looks like Cursor is not a property of GameMenu, merely a child.

Try this:

```
var cursor = new CursorImg();
gameMenu.addChild(cursor);
cursor.name = "cursor";
```

And:

```
gameMenu.getChildByName("cursor").gotoAndStop(1);
```

This isn't really the best way to accomplish what you want but the other methods depend on the structure of your code which I don't know.

Also note that AS3 coding convention for variable names is to use camelCase (first letter of first word lowercase, first letter of next words uppercase).

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the variable `cursor` by `new CursorImg()` then add it to `gameMenu` and you have tried to access `gameMenu.cursor` but really there is no object in that movie `gameMenu` with the name `cursor`. However, you can simply access the attached movie with the variable you defined `cursor`.

```
cursor.gotoAndStop(1);
```

In AS3, you can't access the dynamically added movieclip by it's name like what we did in AS2. You can only access the movie with the help of `getChildByName()` function of `MovieClip` class. So, you can also access that movieclip like

```
var cursor = new CursorImg();
gameMenu.addChild(cursor);
cursor.name = "cursor";
```

then access it anywhere in your `class` like

```
var cursor:MovieClip = gameMenu.getChildByName("cursor") as MovieClip;
cursor.gotoAndStop(1);
```

FYI: Any thing added to stage is commonly packaged under `DisplayObject`, so we need to typecast it inorder to get the right type.

It could be better practicing **camelCase** style for naming `variable` names because the standard way is **camelCase** for vaiables and only for Class the first letter of every word should be **CAPITAL**